# login/logout navigation in Angular

Tags: angular

In my menu, I have an item named `Logout`, When the user clicks on `Logout`, the user isn't direct to the login page but toward the portfolio page. I d'ont understand the problem.

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PortfolioComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },

  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'portfolio',
    component: PortfolioComponent,
  },
```

*app.component.ts*

```
private createLinks() {
    this.links = [
        new NavigationLink(
            'Sélection du portefeuille',
            ['portfolio'],
            'fa fa-credit-card'
        ),
        new NavigationLink(
            'Corporate actions',
            ['corporate-action'],
            'fa fa-university'
        ),
        new NavigationLink('Valeurs', ['value'], 'fa fa-bar-chart'),
        new NavigationLink('Indices Boursiers', ['indice'], 'fa fa-line-chart'),
        new NavigationLink('Devises', ['devise'], 'fa fa-money'),
        new NavigationLink(
            'Tableau de valeurs',
            ['valuable-table'],
            'fa fa-list-alt'
        ),
        new NavigationLink('Logout', ['/login'], 'fa fa-circle-o-notch'),
    ];
}

logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

I can give you my code -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ocoovv?file=src/app/app.component.html), the password is ***test1***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not logging out.

In `navigation-side-panel.component.html`, you're ONLY routerlinking to the login page WITHOUT logging out in your auth service.

In the `login.component.ts` constructor, on line 27, you check if the auth service user is still valid, and navigate to ['/'].